# Align complex, non-matching meshes as closely as possible in size, position and rotation

Tags: modeling, mesh, transforms

I have two complex meshes that I want to align with each other as closely as possible. Not in terms of touching each other (as a lot of questions seems to cover) but actually overlapping with each other.

As an example, I want to turn this:

[image: separate monkeys]

into this:

[image: overlapping monkeys]

through a combination of moving, rotating and scaling.

Clearly I can get a rough result by hand (as above), but is there an automated method I could use that does not rely on my own judgement?

What I have tried/considered already:

- The align tool will do position but not rotation or scaling, and in fact it doesn't even provide the best position since it is based only on the object origins.
- The snap tool will align particular faces but doesn't take the overall shape into account.
- Perhaps there is a modifier that will do it? I don't know much about the various object modifiers.
- EDIT: In contrast to the simple example given here with Suzanne, my objects don't necessarily come with the same orientation relative to their local origin, so e.g. copying rotation information will not work in most cases.

I also understand that there isn't necessarily one single metric that will tell me the "best" alignment between two objects, as there will be different ways to measure this property. I don't mind that too much - the important thing is having a consistent and automated method.

Comment: AFAIK there is no built-in tool to do it in Blender. However there are a number of specialized softwares that can do it, with very efficient tools based on research papers, like CloudCompare (free), import your models, select them both and go tools > Registration > Fine registration (icp)

Comment: How similar are those "complex meshes"? Regarding Chaudhry's answer and my comment on it, do they have the meshes in the same or at least similar position and rotation relative to their origins?

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann The meshes are from different sources (photogrammetry) and don't necessarily have the same rotation relative to the origin, no.

Comment: So the given answer here would not work if not per coincidence those two objects happen to have the same relative mesh locations and rotations. Maybe it would be best to give the information in the question as well, or perhaps even make it visible.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann So won't resetting the origin points by going to the set origin>origin to geometry function be a suitable step? And for example if the origin point has to beon the bottom, both meshes can be selected and move them up on the z axis.

Comment: That depends on how different those two meshes are, origin to geometry can still move them to slightly different locations relative to the mesh. And it doesn't help if the **meshes** (not the **objects**) are rotated differently.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann Then you can reset the location in edit mode.

Comment: @ChaudhryYousuf I'm talking of location and rotation **relative** to the objects origin. Two objects can both be on (0, 0, 0) at the world's center and have rotation (0, 0, 0) but still be different. He says the objects have different sources and not necessarily the same rotation. Take Suzanne, duplicate it, go into Edit Mode, hit R to rotate the mesh and go back into Object Mode. Now you have two Suzannes, but resetting the location and rotation will not align their meshes.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann So isn't it possible to reset the rotation in edit mode?

Comment: @ChaudhryYousuf No, how should it be possible? It's the Edit Mode, you're editing the mesh. If you decide your mesh should be a cube standing 45° on one corner vertex, than this is the mesh without any object rotation. When you decide to edit the mesh to look like this, why should Blender "reset" it to... something? And a cube is a simple object where you can say, well, Blender could make assumptions based on the overall geometry. But this question deals with photogrammetry objects which are slightly more complex I guess.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann So blender doesn't have rotation properties in edit mode? I guess that should be a feature too.

Comment: Have you never worked in Edit Mode?

Answer (score 1):

Very Easy. You can use object constraints. The constraints which will help you are: Copy Location, Copy Rotation, and Copy Scale. Then just add the other object as the target in the constraint. [image]

Comment: In the question he says he has "two complex meshes", not defining any details about them. Your answer works with his example where he has got two Suzannes. The question is if his two meshes all have the origin in the same space and are rotated the same relative to their origin points. If I take one Suzanne from his example, go to _Edit Mode_ and move and rotate the mesh slightly, this will make your answer useless. But that's just a thought since the question isn't clear on these issues.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann is right, unfortunately this won't work in a lot of cases as the objects aren't necessarily oriented in the same way relative to their origins. In my example I used Suzanne just to keep it simple, but in reality I can't use information based on local axes and origins. However, +1 as this does highlight a tool that I can use in some situations, and might also be useful to other readers.